# Convert Lab colour values in RGB and HEX in R

Tags: r, hex, rgb, color-space, cielab

Conversion of `RGB` values into `HEX` values is easy with R:

```
    x <- c("165 239 210", "111 45 93")
    sapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(x)
    rgb(x[1], x[2], x[3], maxColorValue=255))
    #[1] "#A5EFD2" "#6F2D5D"
```

How can I convert CIELab values into RGB and HEX?

```
x <- c("20 0 0", "50 0 0")
[...code...]
#[1] "#303030" "#777777"
```

Comment: Have a look at `?convertColor`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way using `library(colorspace)`

```
library(colorspace)

z <- c("20 0 0", "50 0 0")
b <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(z, split = " "), as.numeric))
b <- LAB(b)
as(b, "RGB")
#output:
              R          G          B
[1,] 0.02989077 0.02989025 0.02989294
[2,] 0.18418803 0.18418480 0.18420138
```

It can not convert directly to HEX but it can convert to: RGB, XYZ, HSV, HLS, LAB, polarLAB, LUV, polarLUV.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` style and `convertColor` function.

```
convert_lab2rgb <- function(x){
    x %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    convertColor(from='Lab', to='sRGB') %>%
    as.vector()
}


convert_rgb2hex <- function(x){
    x %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    `*`(255) %>% 
    round() %>% 
    as.hexmode() %>% 
    paste(collapse='') %>% 
    paste0('#', ., collapse='')    
}


c("20 0 0", "50 0 0") %>% 
    map(~ str_split(., pattern=' ')[[1]]) %>% 
    map(as.numeric) %>%
    map(convert_lab2rgb) %>% 
    map(convert_rgb2hex)


## #303030'
## #777777'
```